# What is these lines of code saying?

Tags: c#, .net

```
    T FindBy(object key);
```

What is the above Line of code saying?

```
  T this[object key] { get; set; }
```

What is this Above line of code? Some say it is an Indexer which I do not fully understand!

Comment: So you have got an answer, and [couldn't find the time to google it](http://tinyurl.com/69pqyel)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is a **method** declaration, with the return value being a **generic type**. The second one is an **indexer property**.

Here's an explanation of what these terms mean:

- [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx)
- [Generics (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)
- [Indexers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. First line is a method which returns the instance of T by using the Key object.
2. Second line is an indexer (a special property type) which return the object. You can find more details from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)